# Port forge gradle to gradle 7 without eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Gradle 7 is needed to build mods on java 16 and java 16 is needed to run mc 1.17 and I don't want to have to choose between ability to build mods for 1.12 or ability to run 1.17 so initially, I just tried running

```
gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.1.1
```

,

but that failed. The instructions for installing forge gradle wanted eclipse but do I really need eclipse?

To repicate this issue, first run git clone -b 1.12-forge https://github.com/FionaTheMortal/better-biome-blend.

Secondly, run cd better-biome-blend

After that, run gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.1.1 on windows or on any other platform, run bash gradlew wrapper --gradle-version=7.1.1.

Lastly, run gradlew build or on any other platform, sh gradlew build and the build will fail.

Comment: Can you give more details? How did it fail? What steps are you taking? What do we need to do to get to the same point as you?

Comment: It's a really problematic to develop for 1.12 and 1.17 at a same time. But you can switch between versions of java, gradle and mc fastly. Just install both versions of java and create some bat/sh scripts for changing environment variables JAVA_HOME

Comment: So you run both java 14 and java 16 at the same time, so how do you make a bat file that does it?